# Python pip3 throws ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

Tags: python, module, installation, pip, package

I have both python 2 and 3 and pip 2 and 3 installed, and all had been working fine.  I tried installing graph-tools (https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/wikis/installation-instructions) using `port install py-graph-tool`, and it seems to have messed with my installations.

Specifically, I can no longer install packages with pip3, e.g.:

```
$ pip3 install networkx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/bin/pip3", line 8, in <module>
    from pip import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

even though

```
$ which pip
/Users/me/bin/pip

$ which pip3
/Users/me/bin/pip3
```

Less immediately, I have had similar problems (I assume) with different Python installations interfering with each other... I have done some searching to better understand this problem, but anyone willing to explain the basics or point to some good explanations online, I would be grateful!

Comment: Try setting the `PYTHONPATH` variable.

Comment: Tried `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/me/bin` and tried again, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Add the `site-packages` or `dist-packages` location to the `PYTHONPATH`, not the binary location. The problem is that it is looking for a module called `pip` not a binary called `pip`

Comment: Many thanks!  That did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You can manually install pip3

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
```

Comment: Have tried that. `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.  Still get the same error.